# How can I evaluate data over time in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, select

I need to find users who have posted three times or more, three months in a row.  I wrote this query:

```
select count(id), owneruserid, extract(month from creationdate) as postmonth from posts
group by owneruserid, postmonth
having count(id) >=3
order by owneruserid, postmonth
```

And I get this:

```
count   owneruserid postmonth
36     -1            1
23     -1            2
45     -1            3
41     -1            4
18     -1            5
24     -1            6
31     -1            7
78     -1            8
83     -1            9
17     -1            10
88     -1            11
127    -1            12
3      6             11
3      7             12
4      8             1
8      8             12
4      12            4
3      12            5
3      22            2
4      22            4
```

(truncated)

Which is great.  How can I query for users who posted three times or more, three months or more in a row?  Thanks.

Comment: Are we assuming all posts are in the same year, and that none of your ranges cross the year boundary? `select extract(month from '2017-01-01'::date), extract(month from '2016-01-01'::date);`

Comment: They happen to be, yes, but it would be better if we could track across years.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the **Islands and Gaps** problem, specifically it's an Island problem with a date range. You should,

1. Fix this question up.
2. Flag it to be sent to dba.stackexchange.com

To solve this,

1. Create a pseudo column with a window that has 1 if the row preceding it does not correspond to the preceding mont
2. Create groups out of that with `COUNT()`
3. Check to make sure the `count(*)` for the group is greater than or equal to three.

Query,

```
SELECT l.id, creationdaterange, count(*)
FROM (

  SELECT t.id,
    t.creationdate,
    count(range_reset) OVER (PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY creationdate) AS creationdaterange
  FROM (
    SELECT id,
    creationdate,
    CASE
      WHEN date_trunc('month',creationdate::date)::date - interval '1 month' = date_trunc('month',lag(creationdate))::date OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY creationdate)
      THEN 1
    END AS range_reset
    FROM post
    ORDER BY id, creationdate
  ) AS t;

) AS l
GROUP BY t.id, creationdaterange
HAVING count(*) >= 3;
```